# Different output between Emulator and Samsung Galaxy S3 with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having issues with the output of the the result of a math calculation. I have a basic average of an array of     double      and I assign the result to a Label object, using the ToString() method. When I emulate the average, the label shows the correct value of 15.96 for example, but the same average of the same array, on my Galaxy S3 shows 159.6.

Is there anyone who know what's up and what can I do to make the S3 show the correct value?

Thank you all!

EDIT: passing the result to a label and adding the label to the grid:

```
            double result = Math.Round(NP122.DoAverage(parameters), 2);

            CustomLabel label = new CustomLabel();
            label.ColNo = grid.ColumnDefinitions.IndexOf(c);
            label.FontSize = 25;
            label.TextColor = Color.Green;

            if (result.ToString() == "NaN")
                label.Text = "0";
            else
                label.Text = result.ToString();
            label.IsVisible = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows.Length + 2; i++) {
                if(i == numberOfRows.Length +1)
                Grid.SetRow(label, i);
            }

            Grid.SetColumn(label, grid.ColumnDefinitions.IndexOf(c));
            listaRez.Add(label);
            foreach (CustomLabel a in listaRez)
            {
                if (a.ColNo == grid.ColumnDefinitions.IndexOf(c))
                {
                    grid.Children.Add(a);
                }                   
            }
```

EDIT 2: Custom function for NP122.DoAverage:

```
 public static class NP122
{
    public static double Vx, sx, Xm, kn, Xkinf, Xksup;
    public static double sum;
    public static double sumaProvizorie;
    public static double[] valoriKn = new double[25];


    public static double ValoareCaracteristicaSuperioara(double[] l)
    {
        Vx = 0;
        sx = 0;
        Xm = 0;
        kn = 0;
        Xkinf = 0;
        Xksup = 0;
        sum = 0;
        sumaProvizorie = 0;

        valoriKn[0] = 0;
       //more here 
        valoriKn[24] = 0.35;


         if (l.Length < 2 )
            {
                Xksup = 0;
                Xkinf = 0;
            }
          else
            {                                      
                Xm = (l.Sum()) / (l.Length);

                for (int j = 0; j < l.Length; j++)
                {
                    sumaProvizorie = Math.Round(Math.Pow((l[j] - Xm), 2), 2);
                    sum += sumaProvizorie;
                }

                kn = valoriKn[l.Length - 1];
                double elements = (1.00 / (l.Length - 1));
                double putere = sum;

                sx = Math.Round(Math.Sqrt(elements * putere), 4);
                Vx = sx / Xm;
                Xksup = Xm * (1 + kn * Vx);
                Xkinf = Xm * (1 - kn * Vx);

            }

        return Xksup;
```

Comment: can you share your code please

Comment: Code added to the question! Thank you Adam!

Comment: is the culture/region/language set differently in the two environments?

Comment: Hello Jason! No, the app still doesn't use localization. Everything is hardcoded in english for the moment.

Comment: Can you please show me what the function NP122.DoAverage looks like. I assume this is a custom function you built yourself?

Comment: @Adam code added, sorry for the delay, was out of internet connection zone!

Comment: Can you please let me know what the actual purpose of your custom function is? I think there might be a simpler solution to it.

Comment: You should also log the output of your function. I highly doubt that the function will return a different value dependent upon the emulator or actual device. It would have to be the globalization settings on your device. On your phone go to the settings icon and change your regional settings there

Comment: Hello Adam! Thank you for the reply! To answer your first comment, the function represents a statistical way to obtain a representative value from an array of values, and unfortunately this is the way it should be done. As for the second comment, yes that is the problem! After setting the phone to english everything works like a charm! My guess is the imperial units, setting double values with dot(,) instead of comma(,). However now I need to find a way to update this in Xamarin as well ( the numeric keyboard from Xamarin does not contain comma for calculations just dot). That was the problem!